# Vectors and matrices in C

Tags: c, vector, return

I would like to perform vectorial operations in C but I don't know how to return a vector from a function. I tried to generate a vector in this way:

```
float *generate_vector()
{
    static float vec[3];
    return vec;  
}
```

However, calling this function using

```
int main (void)
{

  float vec[3];
  vec = generate_vector();

}
```

leads to an error (error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘float[3]’ from type ‘float *’). Interestingly, this error doesn't occur when only a component of the vector is called using vec[1] = &generate_vector()[1].

Could you help me with this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `float *vec = generate_vector();`

Comment: `float *vec` would be syntactically correct and would help to let this code compile, but it doesnt't help much:  the function itself is pretty useless. As it returns a pointer to a statically allocated array, you can essentially only call it once (trying to "generate" two different vectors through it and e.g. multiplying them would yield pretty unexpected results).
The function is named misleading, btw., since it doesn't generate anything which wasn't there before.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here, the first is you can't assign an array like this:

```
vec = generate_vector();
```

Arrays decay to pointers when they're passed, but in the function where it's declared it's an array, and you can't assign a pointer to it like this.

You need to declare a pointer to get the returned array:

```
float *vec = generate_vector();
```

Just FYI, a second option you might be interested in, if you want to generate a new array from this function you can do it dynamically.

```
float *vec = malloc(3 * sizeof(float));
```

then you need to free that later when you're done.

Comment: The local array is static so it will not deallocate when going out of scope

Comment: @thisisdog - Yeah, totally missed that he declaired it `static`, you are correct, that point is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a different approach if you like. It's a little less efficient but might be easier to understand (and probably easier to handle in a complex program).

In C, you can't return an array. You either need to `malloc()` a buffer (which you need to keep track of and later `free()` it) or you need to declare a "return array" outside the function and pass an additional pointer to it into your functions.

So there is the inability to return an array. But hey, here is a nice workaround: you actually *can* return a `struct` *that contains* an array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct vec
{
    double v[3];
};  

struct vec multiply_scalar(struct vec v, double scalar)
{
    int i;
    struct vec ret;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        ret.v[i] = v.v[i] * scalar;
    }   
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned you are returning a pointer so you need to assign it to a pointer variable. In addition, using a static array like this is a bad idea. It would be better to take the vector in like this:

```
void generate_vector(float * inVector)
```

This way the memory management is handled outside of the function and you won't accidentally use the same vector in multiple places.

With your setup a user of the function could write this code:

```
float * vectorA = generate_vector();
float * vectorB = generate_vector();
```

They may not expect that vectorA and vectorB are actually the same thing and this would lead to bugs.

Comment: Plus need to pass to the function the size of the vector. Maybe `void generate_vector(float * inVector, size_t size)`

Comment: I was assuming the user knows the vector is of size 3, but yes you are right for complete generality

Answer (score 0):

When doing these things in C, I tend to reserve the return value of a function for an indicator that a function has succeded or failed. The input and output arrays I tend to pass as parameters.

Some years ago I wrote a Perl script to generate loop-unrolled matrix and vector code. (Like C++ templates, but for C) An example of the output is this function to transform a vector with a matrix.

```
/* Multiplies a matrix with a vector */
extern void mat_xform3(double m[3][3], double v[3], double mv[3]);
```

Implementation:

```
#ifndef NULL
#define NULL (void*)0
#endif

/* If the product of the multiplication of two doubles is less than EPS,
 * the value is set to 0. */
#define EPS 1e-8

void mat_mul3(double a[3][3], double b[3][3], double ab[3][3])
{
        double res[3][3];
        assert(a!=NULL); assert(b!=NULL); assert(ab!=NULL);
        res[0][0]  = a[0][0]*b[0][0];
        res[0][0] += a[0][1]*b[1][0];
        res[0][0] += a[0][2]*b[2][0];
        if (res[0][0] < EPS && res[0][0] > -EPS) {res[0][0] = 0.0;}
        res[0][1]  = a[0][0]*b[0][1];
        res[0][1] += a[0][1]*b[1][1];
        res[0][1] += a[0][2]*b[2][1];
        if (res[0][1] < EPS && res[0][1] > -EPS) {res[0][1] = 0.0;}
        res[0][2]  = a[0][0]*b[0][2];
        res[0][2] += a[0][1]*b[1][2];
        res[0][2] += a[0][2]*b[2][2];
        if (res[0][2] < EPS && res[0][2] > -EPS) {res[0][2] = 0.0;}
        res[1][0]  = a[1][0]*b[0][0];
        res[1][0] += a[1][1]*b[1][0];
        res[1][0] += a[1][2]*b[2][0];
        if (res[1][0] < EPS && res[1][0] > -EPS) {res[1][0] = 0.0;}
        res[1][1]  = a[1][0]*b[0][1];
        res[1][1] += a[1][1]*b[1][1];
        res[1][1] += a[1][2]*b[2][1];
        if (res[1][1] < EPS && res[1][1] > -EPS) {res[1][1] = 0.0;}
        res[1][2]  = a[1][0]*b[0][2];
        res[1][2] += a[1][1]*b[1][2];
        res[1][2] += a[1][2]*b[2][2];
        if (res[1][2] < EPS && res[1][2] > -EPS) {res[1][2] = 0.0;}
        res[2][0]  = a[2][0]*b[0][0];
        res[2][0] += a[2][1]*b[1][0];
        res[2][0] += a[2][2]*b[2][0];
        if (res[2][0] < EPS && res[2][0] > -EPS) {res[2][0] = 0.0;}
        res[2][1]  = a[2][0]*b[0][1];
        res[2][1] += a[2][1]*b[1][1];
        res[2][1] += a[2][2]*b[2][1];
        if (res[2][1] < EPS && res[2][1] > -EPS) {res[2][1] = 0.0;}
        res[2][2]  = a[2][0]*b[0][2];
        res[2][2] += a[2][1]*b[1][2];
        res[2][2] += a[2][2]*b[2][2];
        if (res[2][2] < EPS && res[2][2] > -EPS) {res[2][2] = 0.0;}
        memcpy(ab, res, 3*3*sizeof(double));
}
```

In this case, the function cannot fail, so it returns `void`. But a function to e.g. invert a matrix *can* fail, so that returned a value indicating success or failure.

The Perl script could generate code for matrices of arbitrary size. Leave a comment if you'd want it.